# Where condition based on link table

Tags: sql, sql-server, datatables

I have a table of `Users`. Each `User` can be in multiple `Disciplines`, and they are linked by a link table, `User_Discipline`. The tables are pretty straight forward:

```
User
ID     Name          more...
3   |  John Doe    | ...
7   |  Jane Smith  | ...
12  |  Joe Jones   | ...

Discipline 
ID     name
1   |  Civil
2   |  Mechanical
3   |  Piping

User_Discipline
UserID       DisciplineID
3        |   2
3        |   1
7        |   2
12       |   3
```

Say John Doe is the logged in user. **He needs to be able to select a list of all of the users in any of his disciplines.** In the given example, I need a query that would return a list with John and Jane, since John is both Civil and Mechanical, and Jane is in Mechanical.

I think sub-selects are involved, but all the reading I've done so far have shown how to do subselects checking for one value (say, John's Civil `Discipline`). I need to be able to perform a query that runs a `WHERE` condition but matches any of John's `Disciplines` many-to-many with others' `Disciplines`.

I'm using the [DataTables Editor .NET library](https://editor.datatables.net/manual/net/conditions) to do the SQL, but I can translate an answer in regular SQL markup to that library. The only limitation of the library that I might encounter here is that everything would have to be done in one SQL statement. I appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you try anything?

Comment: Where's your query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT [User].ID, [User].Name
FROM [User]
  JOIN User_Discipline
    ON [User].ID = User_Discipline.UserID
WHERE 
  User_Discipline.DisciplineID IN (
    SELECT DisciplineID
    FROM User_Discipline
    WHERE UserID = <<John Doe's userID>>
  )
```

Comment: OR `WHERE UserID = (Select ID FROM User WHERE name  = 'John Doe')`

Comment: The OP was not clear on this. It could be that they have the ID from John Doe's log in.

Comment: From the OP: ** I need a query that would return a list with John and Jane, since John is both Civil and Mechanical, and Jane is in Mechanical.**

Comment: But you need the distinct as @Jonathan answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all with inner joins:

```
declare @users table (id int, fullname varchar(50)) 
declare @disciplines table (id int, discname varchar(50))
declare @userdisciplines table (userid int, discid int)

insert into @users VALUES (3, 'John Doe') 
insert into @users VALUES (7, 'Jane Smith')
insert into @users VALUES (12, 'Joe Jones')

insert into @disciplines VALUES (1, 'Civil') 
insert into @disciplines VALUES (2, 'Mechanical') 
insert into @disciplines VALUES (2, 'Piping') 

insert into @userdisciplines VALUES (3, 2)
insert into @userdisciplines VALUES (3, 1)
insert into @userdisciplines VALUES (7, 2) 
insert into @userdisciplines VALUES (12, 3)

SELECT distinct id, fullname from @users u 
INNER JOIN @userdisciplines ud ON ud.userid = u.id
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ud.discid FROM @users u 
inner join @userdisciplines ud on ud.userid = u.id 
WHERE u.fullname = 'John Doe') d ON d.discid = ud.discid
```

Comment: I would change to `DISTINCT ID, FULLNAME` there is always the chance two different users have the same name.